# creating an object with hours through the user interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having trouble creating the right object. I have a calendar that stores the hours. He wants timeTable to hold such an object, for example

```
"timeTable":{
    "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"18:00"}],
    "1": [{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}]
  }
```

How, after clicking the save button, send such an object to:

```
 timeTable: Map<number, Array<HourScheduleDefinitionModel>>;
```

interface:

```
interface HourScheduleDefinitionModel {
  from: string;
  to: string;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e92ezv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The code you've share here doesn't explain the problem you have. Please consider re-writing and adding the relevant part of the code that is not working.

Comment: it's about the save () method, I don't know how to rewrite it

Comment: Be advised that if there is no JSON representation of a Map so if you're intending to persist it as JSON you'll need to convert it to a plain old JavaScript object before you do so.

Comment: Note that the type that represents your sample data is not a Map either but rather `timeTable: {[key string]: Array<HourScheduleDefinitionModel>} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getTimeline = () => {
  result = []
  for(item of data){
    var start = -1, timeline = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < item.items.length; i++){
      if(item.items[i] === 1){
        if(start === -1) {
          start = i;
        }
      }else{
        if(start !== -1){
          timeline.push({"from": start < 10 ? "0" + start + ":00" : start + ":00" , "to": i < 10 ? "0" + i + ":00" : i + ":00"});
          start = -1;
        }
      }
  
      if(start !== -1 && i === item.items.length - 1){
        timeline.push({"from": start < 10 ? "0" + start + ":00" : start + ":00" , "to": "00:00"});
      }
    }
  
    result.push({ 
      day: item.name,
      timeline : timeline
    })
  }
  return result;  
}
```

example data :-

```
data = [
  {
    name: 'Monday',
    items: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    active: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Tuesday',
    items: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    active: true
  }
]
```

result :-

```
console.log(getTimeline(data));

[
  {
  day: 'Monday',
  timeline: [
      { from: '01:00', to: '02:00' },
      { from: '03:00', to: '04:00' },
      { from: '20:00', to: '00:00' }
    ]
  },

  {
    day: 'Tuesday',
    timeline: [ { from: '01:00', to: '04:00' }, { from: '20:00', to: '21:00' } ]
  }
]
```

Comment: wow, thanks. Why is the object the same for Monday and Tuesday? https://zapodaj.net/1df353a15f46b.png.html

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of adding a new map to your object storage. Please note that the `timeTable` type is not used in the code as the comment of [@AluanHaddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) is the same as what I was trying to explain.

```js
    var hours = {"timeTable":{
        "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"18:00"}],
        "1": [{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}]
      }};

    interface HourScheduleDefinitionModel {
      from: string;
      to: string;
    }

    var newHour: HourScheduleDefinitionModel = {
      from: "09:00",
      to: "10:00"
    }

    var key = 2;
    var value = [newHour];
    hours.timeTable[key.toString()] = value

    console.log(hours)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/G4QwTgBAFg9grmAzgLgiAdgTwgXggbwCIAXASwFsBTAFRACMAbSw5fAKAk4kIAYWIA2kQBmYGORa8AHMh58ANCRiSAjACZZfAL7yChUeNUAWTYUXFlyQiplzCWgLryOXa-yH6xEqz1sKlqgBspo4uWloA3GxspOjElGDCIADGlBAAEvBgAMrJUJQAJnBMACKUwrGkZDDoALIwBZQMBC4G5KiIxGCxAOZRnBYdXb1RWtGgkOiUAO6ZCKhzOXmFxZRlFehVpDX1jc147JxtqLwAnKbOAzAnKjymbGNsExAA1pTYeGpRz6AMcGl4ARTWZZBxRWAIRAAOjIVFojEoAjemBhMGyw3QPQAFABKBy4CC-f7RZI1RAwJhQhgwbEQpA4oA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an array (indexed by numbers) instead of an object (indexed by strings):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=14&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHsCuUDKCAWEAJpgDYQAiEMowYw6IAsukRKcgN4CwAUMshhR0AWwBcyAM5gooAOYBuPgLDoJ02SEV8Avnz5gAngAcUAFWAiIZuACNyyALzIAFBmx5CJclRog6DMys7ADaALoAlOFKvHwIjNLIYGASFlY29ijOIcrIIZwAREKiBWIFAAwAHGLl5QUANAWqpQUAjABMNXU69VxFwiItrQAsXQ1N6EPVtQU6Yb0A9AvI5bn5-SVlVWONzWWtAGxjc4vLrXxhMXEJ6OQAdKToci7JIeWRMfEgkrcQD08vMAhVofPhAA)

```ts
interface HourScheduleDefinitionModel {
  from: string;
  to: string;
}

type TimeTable = (HourScheduleDefinitionModel[])[];

const tt: TimeTable = [
  [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"18:00"}], // 0
  [{"from":"08:00","to":"16:00"}], // 1
];

console.log(tt[0]);
console.log(tt[1]);
```